# Formal definition of limit x tends to a

Tags: real-analysis

The question states

a) Give the formal definition of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$

b) Prove, by using the forma definition of the limit, that $\lim_{x\to a}5x+5=5a+5.$

So far I have:

a) For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ (which depends on $\epsilon$) such that

$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ wherever, $0<|x-a|<\delta(\epsilon)$

b) $|5x+5-5a+5|=|5x-5a|=5|x-a|$

$|5x+5-5a+5|=5|x-a|<\epsilon$

I am a little stuck after this point, does $δ=\epsilon/5$?

and therefore $|5x+5-5a+5|=5|x-a|<\epsilon$ wherever $|x-a|<\epsilon/5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scratch work you did above to find the correct $\delta$ is correct. However, that work should not appear in the proof. The proof should look something like this.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary and choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{5}$. Then, for all $x$ satisfying $|x-a|<\delta$, we have

$$
|5x+5−5a+5|=|5x−5a|=5|x−a|<5\delta=5\frac{\epsilon}{5}=\epsilon.
$$

Therefore, since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\lim_{x\to a}5x+5=5a+5$.